# How can I tell if a document is 'being published'?

Tags: event-handlers, event-receivers, splistitem, document, publishing

I need to use the relevant event receiver to tell if a document is being published, is this possible? I will settle for has 'just been published' - i.e. I have no preference between `itemupdating` and `itemupdated`.

**What I've Tried**

I've tried both itemupdating and itemupdated with the following code:

```
   private Boolean IsBeingPublished(SPItemEventProperties properties)
   {
       Int32 beforeVersion, afterVersion;

       beforeVersion = Convert.ToInt32(properties.BeforeProperties["vti_level"]);
       afterVersion = Convert.ToInt32(properties.AfterProperties["vti_level"]);

       return beforeVersion == afterVersion;
   }
```

This doesn't work, it's true most of the time so doesn't indicate whether it's been published or not.

Any help GREATLY appreciated. I need this to consistently tell me whether the event was fired because of a publish action or not.

Comment: +1 for the interesting question. Just a suggestion, you could see if reflector gives any hint - have a look at the publish function that is called from the UI - maybe there is some other field you can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some experimenting based on the answer provided by C. Marius I've come to the following conclusion:

If you are using `ItemUpdating`:

```
public override void ItemUpdating(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    if (properties.ListItem != null &&
        properties.ListItem.ModerationInformation != null &&
        properties.ListItem.ModerationInformation.Status == 
            SPModerationStatusType.Pending &&
        properties.AfterProperties["vti_doclibmodstat"] != null &&
        properties.AfterProperties["vti_doclibmodstat"].ToString() ==
            ((int)SPModerationStatusType.Approved).ToString())
    {
        // Item is about to be approved and published.
    }
    base.ItemUpdating(properties);
}
```

If you are using `ItemUpdated`:

```
public override void ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    if (properties != null &&
        properties.ListItem != null &&
        properties.ListItem.ModerationInformation != null &&
        properties.ListItem.ModerationInformation.Status == 
            SPModerationStatusType.Approved &&
        properties.ListItem.Level == SPFileLevel.Published)
    {
        // Item was just approved and published.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is actually no such type of event (something there is ONLY for files - using SPFileLevel.Published by getting it from Versions property), rather use a combination of validations, such as if this is a SPCheckinType.MajorCheckIn, as well as SPModerationInformation on the actual list item via the ModerationInformation.

However you would also need to do this only after checking if the actual List has ModerationEnabled (requiring Approval) and also if Major/Minor is enabled via the EnableVersioning.